# mount: / is busy

Tags: mount

I have a late 2014 mac mini with the latest osx and parallels installed.
I'm trying to install elementary os in parallels but every time I boot into the live os or install I get

```
ACPI PCC FAILED
```

If I play around in live mode/ or install, when I reboot or shutdown it gets stuck on

```
mount: / is busy
```

Also tried in virtualbox with same issues.

How can I get it working without these errors?

Keep in mind I'm new to linux.

I like how it looks and want to give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

this happened because you did not dismount о drive on the virtual machine.